# Better way of storing more elements and then randomly selecting specific quantities of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

Hi I'm extremely new to python and was just wondering if anyone could help me/point me in the right direction, to improve my code.

```
import random

goal_keeper = ["Neuer","Allison", "De Gea"]
defender = ["Varane", "Ramos", "Thiago Silva","Chiellini", "Shaw", "Alaba"]
midfielder = ["De Bruyne", "Frenandes", "Modric", "Thiago","Sane", "Rashford"]
attacker = ["Lewandowski","Messi","Ronaldo","Mbappe","Neymar","Kane"]

i = int(input("How many players do you want?: "))
n_plyr = 0
squad = []
while n_plyr < i:
    position_input = input("Select the players position: ")
    n = int(input("How many players in that position?: "))
    n_plyr = n_plyr + n
    print(i-n_plyr, "left to pick for your squad")

    if position_input == "goal keeper":
        gk_players = random.choices(goal_keeper, k=n)
        squad.append(gk_players)
    if position_input == "defender":
        def_players = random.choices(defender, k=n)
        squad.append(def_players)
    if position_input == "midfielder":
        mid_players = random.choices(midfielder, k=n)
        squad.append(mid_players)
    if position_input == "attacker":
        atk_players = random.choices(attacker, k=n)
        squad.append(atk_players)
    if n_plyr > i:
        n_plyr = n_plyr - n
        print("Squad is too big only", i-n_plyr, "left to pick")

print(routine)
```

The code does work im not sure how to adapt it to adding more players as expanding the list doesn't seem the right thing to do especially if I wanna add hundreds of each position. what is the best way at storing a lot more elements and then still being able to select a random number of them like i tried to above?. Also any other suggestions will be appreciated, just trying to learn and improve :)

Comment: Maybe Google about for other examples, see what they do, expand yours similar to them or in better/more interesting way.  Examples: https://gist.github.com/codeboy101/81e417f94299fe803e4a, https://github.com/topics/football-manager?q=python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. SO is meant for specific problems, so people here are going to focus on your main question and not the other problems with your code. You could ask on [codereview.se] if you'd like.

Comment: That said, you might consider using a dict to store the players instead of separate variables like `goal_keeper` etc. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341) Then you could simplify all the `if position_input == ...` down to `random.choices(players[position_input], k=n)`

Answer (score 1):

In the end, if you have a list with hundreds of players you will need to define them somewhere. To keep the code clean I would create a file for each position and then have one player name per line. Then you can do the following:

```
with open('defender.txt','r') as f:
    defender = f.readlines()
```

Like this you can have a file with hundreds of players without messing up your code.